# Let $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $g(0) = g^\prime(0) = 0$ and $g^{\prime\prime}(0)$ exists and is positive.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $g(0) = g^\prime(0) = 0$ and $g^{\prime\prime}(0)$ exists and is positive. Prove that there exists $x > 0$ such that $g(x) > 0$.

Using the definition of derivative I get $g^{\prime\prime}(0)=\dfrac {g(2x)-g(x)}{x^2}>0$ for $x$ which tends to $0$. Which means that for every $h>0$ there exists $y$ such that for every $x\in (-y,y)$  we have $|g(2x)-g(x)|<x^2h$. I'm not sure if this way will bring to a proof of if I should try a different way.

Comment: Can you use the Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: The relation $g''(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(2x)-g(x)}{x^2}$ does not follow from definition of derivative. Instead use the meaning of sign of derivative. If derivative is positive at $c$ then values of original function to the right of $c$ are greater than its value at $c$ and values to left of $c$ are less than its value at $c$. Applying this to $g''(0)>0$.

Comment: You can prove much more : there is an interval of type $I=(-h, h) $ such that $f(x) >0$ for all $x\in I, x\neq 0$. The given condition is a sufficient test for local minima and $g$ has a strict local minimum at $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that for small $x>0,$

$$\frac{g'(x)}{x}=\frac{g'(x)-g'(0)}{x-0}>g''(0)/2 > 0.$$

It follows that $g'(x) >0$ in some interval $(0,a].$ Thus $g$ is strictly increasing on $[0,a].$ Since $g(0)=0,$ we have $g>0$ in $(0,a].$

Answer (score 2):

Try a Taylor expansion:
$$
g(x) = g(0) + g'(0) x + \frac{1}{2}g''(0)x^2 + R(x) = \frac{1}{2}g''(0)x^2 + R(x),
$$
where $R(x)$ is the remainder term and is $o(x^2)$, i.e. $\lim_{x \to 0}R(x)/x^2 = 0$. If we divide both sides by $x^2$, then
$$
\frac{g(x)}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}g''(0) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{R(x)}{x^2}.
$$
Now use the definition of the limit to make the second term on the right ``very small.''